# Sorting data in dictionaries by highest number in a list assigned as a value? python

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

How would i refer to the first, second and third element in a list that is assigned to a key in a dictionary form? The dictionary is a students name with a list assigned to it with their scores in. How do I refer to each of the scores in that list so that I can remove the smaller one, and later on calculate an average from these scores and print them. 
The dictionary looks like this

```
{'Student Example ': [5, 2], 'Student Name ': [2], 'Another Student ': [1]}
```

whilst the code im trying to use looks like

```
    viewscores = input ("Would you like to view the scoreboards? (Yes/No): ")
if viewscores == "Yes":
    classview = int (input ("What class board would you like to view? (1,2 or 3): "))
    print ("Sort class",classn,"scoreboard: ")
    print ("1. Alphabetically by students highscore")
    print ("2. By high score, highest to lowest")
    print ("3. By average score, highest to lowest")
    sorting = int (input("Enter sort type: (1,2 or 3): "))

    if classview == 1:
        if sorting == 1:
            highscores = ((k, classone[k]) for k in sorted(classone, key=classone.get, reverse=True))
            for k, v in highscores:
                listnum = len(v)
                while listnum > 1:
                    if (v[1]) < (v[0]):
                        del (v[1])
                print (v,k)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emily_000\Desktop\test task 3 part two.py", line 116, in <module>
    if (v[1]) < (v[0]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How could I refer to the indexs of the lists so that I can find the highest score out of them , then sort (by highest to lowest, and alphabetically) . Then how could i refer to them so i can calculate an average out of the scores and organise by this number? 
using python 3.3.4

This is for a school project so could you explain how it works so I can understand, thank you for any help

Comment: Which line is the error on? Can you reduce the problem to a few lines of code?

Comment: I get a 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\georg_000\Desktop\test task 3 part two.py", line 116, in <module>
    if (v[1]) < (v[0]):
IndexError: list index out of range' error

Comment: The issue is that you don't update `listnum` when you delete an element. You're probably better off simply using `len(v)` in its place for your loop condition.

Answer (score 1):

As for your first question:

```
averagescores = {}
for k, v in highscores.items():
    averagescores[k] = float(sum(v))/float(len(v))
```

The above code will average out all the scores and put them in a new dictionary called 'averagescores'.

As for your second question, dictionaries by default are *orderless*. You can, though, get an ordered *representation* of the dictionary as tuples:

```
import operator
sortedscores = sorted(averagescores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

This will sort the scores from least to most by value.

Comment: Thank you for the response! but i received this error when using the average code, why might this be? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\georg_000\Desktop\test task 3 part two.py", line 121, in <module>
    averagescores[v] = sum(v)/len(v)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Whoops! averagescores[v] should be averagescores[k]. Correcting now.

Comment: After the correction, my code is still showing '[5, 4] Georgia Steele 
[2] Student Name 
[1] Another Student ' which has the two list elements 'un averaged', to me 'v' made more sense then k, may you know why it hasnt worked this time?

Comment: Are you printing the new `averagescores` dict or the original one? The suggested method never modifies the original data, it creates new data.

Comment: averagescores = {}
                highscores = ((k, classone[k]) for k in sorted(classone, key=classone.get, reverse=True))
                for k, v in highscores:
                    averagescores[k] = sum(v)/len(v) This is the exact code

Comment: I updated the code, and it should work correctly now.